# React state variable assignment by reference or value?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Say you use the useState hook to set some state:

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');
```

If I set some variable to text and setText like:

```
let textCopy = text;
let setTextCopy = setText;
```

If I try and use `setTextCopy('Some text')`, would this actually update both text and textCopy?

If this does not work, what would be the best way to approach this?

**I know this is probably not a great question I just wasn't sure how to word it. If you have any helpful links I would appreciate it.**

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253)

Answer (score 0):

You are right and wrong.

```
  // this means textCopy will be same as text content
  const textCopy = text
  // this means setTextCopy is Identical as setText
  const setTextCopy = setText
```

when you call `setText`, it'll change `text` in next cycle, and then once it enters the render, `textCopy` will be in sync with same content.

But if you ask me if `textCopy` is Identical as `text`, the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks, why is textCopy not identical to text?

Comment: because it's string, when assigning a string, it'll always allocating to new memory. However if it's a function or object, it's not the case. Since the ref can be assigned.